# Device Access rate limit

Tags: nest-device-access

I'm using the [Device Access Sandbox](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/project) environment and getting a `RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED` error response from the API with the message set to "Rate limited".

How do I know when I'm going to hit the rate limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rate limits have been implemented in Device Access Sandbox to prevent over-utilization of devices and services. Rate limits are configured slightly differently for API methods, commands, and device instances, so there are a few different ways you could be hitting a rate limit.

Typical usage of Device Access with Nest devices shouldn't hit the rate limit. For example, if you wish to keep a history of temperature and humidity changes for a Nest Thermostat, there's really no need to check the temperature and humidity values more than 10 times in a minute (the `devices.get` limit)—they do not fluctuate enough in that time period to make such granularity useful.

To see all the rate limits applied to the Sandbox, see [User and Rate Limits](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/project/limits).

Comment: Given that I've got 16 cameras and 3 thermostats, among other devices, I'm unsure how to stay under the 10/min rate, and actually have anything usable.  I can't even load up camera thumbnails, let alone live video, without hitting the rate limit.

Comment: Use the pubsub feed to get updates when device traits change.